# How to sync <range> with the video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing custom controls for my video. As of now I have a `Play/Pause` button and a seekbar (`<range>` tag). I am unable to sync the seekbar to the video. Here is what I tried:

```
$("#seekbar").val(video.duration);
```

However, it doesnt work.

**Javascript**:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#play_pause_button").click(function(){
            var video = document.getElementById("video");
            if(video.paused){
                video.play();
                $("#play_pause_button").prop("value", "Pause");
                $("#seekbar").val(video.duration);
            }
            else{
                video.pause();
                $("#play_pause_button").prop("value", "Play");
            }                       
        });
    });
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container">
    <video id="video" src="podcast_teaser.mp4" ></video>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="play_pause_button" value="Play" />
    <input type="range" id="seekbar" min="0" max="10" />
</div>
```

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this instead:

```
var factor = $("#seekbar").attr('max');
$("#seekbar").val(video.currentTime / video.duration * factor);
```

This will normalize the current progress (currentTime / duaration). This will produce 0 for the beginning, 1 for end and any fraction between for whatever the current position is.

To make it usable you need to scale it up so that 1 represents the max value (you can set your max to 100 or more for a higher resolution of the slider).

Note: Firefox currently has an issue with fractional values in input where type=range. A workaround is to create a custom progress bar which is click enabled and using the mouse position to set the time instead.

**Update**

This code will of course need to be called frequently using either a time update event or a loop, for example:

```
var isPlaying = false;
var factor = $("#seekbar").attr('max');

function updateSeekbar() {
    $("#seekbar").val(video.currentTime / video.duration * factor);
    if (isPlaying) requestAnimationFrame(updateSeekbar);
}
```

Then in your play button start the loop:

```
...
if(video.paused){
    video.play();
    isPlaying = !video.paused;
    updateSeekbar(),
    ...
```

And in your pause button reset the flag:

```
    isPlaying = false;
```

If you don't need update per frame (monitor frame) then you can use `setTimeout()` instead of `requestAnimationFrame`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried that. Didnt work. I need to sync the seekbar so that when I hit Play, the seekbar keeps on moving ahead.

Comment: @RahulDesai you need to call the lines above inside a time update event or use a loop to poll the values. Please see updated answer.